# How can I change the width of the image in the welcome and finish pages in NSIS so that it will look like a background?

Tags: image, background, dialog, width, nsis

I want to create an installer in which in the welcome and finish pages instead of a banner on the left side, there is a background image that covers the whole width of the dialog.

Answer (score 2):

The Welcome and Finish pages are custom NSIS pages created with [nsDialogs](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html). However, if you want a bitmap to cover the entire dialog then you need to do some modifications to the actual UI files as well.

1. Copy ...\NSIS\Contrib\UIs\modern.exe to myui.exe
2. Use [Resource Hacker](http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/) to add a bitmap control to dialog 105.
3. At the top of your .nsh, define MUI_UI to the path of myui.exe
4. Create custom pages with nsDialogs to mimic the Welcome and Finish pages. Before calling `nsDialogs::Show` you need to:

   1. Call `SetCtlColors` on the custom dialog handle to make it transparent.
   2. Extract your custom .bmp to $PluginsDir.
   3. Call `LoadAndSetImage` to load the image into the control you created in dialog 105.

If you don't want to do all of this yourself you can use the [Graphical Installer](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Graphical_Installer) 3rd-party product.

Here is an example using the page area:

```
!include MUI2.nsh
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW MyHijackWelcome
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
Page Custom MyFullBitmapPage
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

!include nsDialogs.nsh
PEAddResource "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Header\orange-nsis.bmp" "#Bitmap" "#1337" ; Lazy way to include an image
Function MyFullBitmapPage
ShowWindow $mui.Branding.Background ${SW_HIDE}
ShowWindow $mui.Branding.Text ${SW_HIDE}
nsDialogs::Create 1044
Pop $1

${NSD_CreateLabel} 10u 25u 100% 12u "Hello world"
Pop $2
SetCtlColors $2 000000 transparent

${NSD_CreateBitmap} 0 0 100% 100% ""
Pop $2
LoadAndSetImage /EXERESOURCE /RESIZETOFIT $2 0 0 1337 $3
nsDialogs::Show
${NSD_FreeBitmap} $3
ShowWindow $mui.Branding.Background ${SW_SHOW}
ShowWindow $mui.Branding.Text ${SW_SHOW}
FunctionEnd

Function MyHijackWelcome
SendMessage $mui.WelcomePage.Image ${STM_SETIMAGE} 0 0
${NSD_FreeBitmap} $mui.WelcomePage.Image.Bitmap
${NSD_CreateBitmap} 0 0 100% 100% ""
Pop $mui.WelcomePage.Image
LoadAndSetImage /EXERESOURCE /RESIZETOFIT $mui.WelcomePage.Image 0 0 1337 $mui.WelcomePage.Image.Bitmap
SetCtlColors $mui.WelcomePage.Title 000000 transparent
SetCtlColors $mui.WelcomePage.Text 000000 transparent
FunctionEnd
```

If you want the bitmap to extend outside the bounds of the page area you have to use my initial suggestion with `!define MUI_UI`+`GetDlgItem`+`LoadAndSetImage`.

Comment: I didn't understand it. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Which step did you not understand?

Comment: Everything. I expected to see simple script lines that I can just add to the script in order to add a background image to these dialogs, by changing the width of the image that already exists in these dialogs.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service, you have to put in some effort yourself. You have not even completed your other questions on this site, why should I spend any more time writing for you?

Comment: You don't have to give me the whole script, but only the lines needed to create this background image.

Comment: Alright, I made my own UI base file for NSIS: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h-uDzKnNkGLFir4wdotntlBA2AowOI4G/view?usp=sharing

What else should I do?

Comment: That looks alright but if you don't care about it covering the absolute bottom of the window with those buttons you might get away with just using the page area, I'll try to make a simpler example...

Comment: I don't want this image to cover the bottom of the window with the buttons, I want it to cover only the welcome and finish pages. I also tried the script you sended to me, and the commands "PEAddResource" and "LoadAndSetImage" are invalid unfortunately.

Comment: Upgrade to the latest NSIS, v3.08.

Comment: hello , this is working , but how to add to all pages the same image ?